# Pull chain fully retracted on ceiling fan

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

The pull chain that turns the lights on/off on a ceiling fan has fully retracted into the housing. Is this fixable without installing a new pull chain switch?

Comment: Is the switch disassemblable? How about a pic or 2?

Comment: you coild try a bar magnet, or one of those magnet-ended tools

Answer (score 2):

Just about all the switches I have encountered over the years can be taken apart to reroute the chain. Some have screws you can just remove, some have metal screws that have to be removed with pliers. Before you try to take the switch apart, remove it from the fixture and just shake it slowly to see if you can get the tip of the chain out. If this doesn't work, then apart it goes. Separate the two halves carefully because there are some springy contacts in there and you don't want them flying across the room.